# How can you improve solubility of colloidally dispersed substances?

Tags: biochemistry

If you solve collidally dispersed substances then the particles can form large colloids. This may block narrow passages and diffusion into dense structures may become completely impossible.

What can you do to improve the solubility of such substances?

Comment: This sounds pretty inorganic chemistry-ish. Any way to phrase it more towards biochemistry (i.e. relationship to proteins, biological systems, etc...)?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, three-four rounds of sonication greatly helps in having smaller and more homogeneous hydrophobic particles dispersed in water.